# How to dynamically add data to lightning component attributes and render it on page

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

i have a requirement to dynamically generate multiple tables as per the i fetch from Salesforce Database.

for creating a table, i have a separate lightning component. So i configured in such a way that i would pass data to that component would build table and display.

So i need to dynamically display these tables, depending on the size of wrapper data i got from Salesforce DB.

i am using aura:method in child component that build this table and it is called from parent component. can somebody suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understood your problem completely But i think You can iterate over your data in Both in Component and in js do to do So.

```
<aura:attribute name="IteraTableData" type="Object[]" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.IteraTableData}" var="item">
     <c:childComponent aura:id="childComponent">
</aura:iteration>
```

In js You can do

```
>     var iterable = component.get('v.IteraTableData');
>     var childComp = component.find('childComponent');
>     for(var i =0;i<iterable.length;i++){
>         childComp[i].callMethod(); 
>     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) to create your component dynamically